# Can the socket.id of a client be used for malicious activity?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am working on a multiplayer game where the coordinates, size and states of players are stored in a JSON object 'playersPublic' which holds the players' public data also as JSON objects and the key to each player is their socket.id. It is important to have this as key as it is unique and I do have other JSON objects with the players' private data (with the same keys) and when working with the data of a single player, matching their data in the public object with the private object (which happens quite often) needs to happen by key to avoid excessive looping.

In every frame, I need to send the public information (coordinates, state, etc.) of all players to all players so that in the front end each player can update their map accordingly. The first approach I took is to simply have

> setInterval(function() { io.sockets.emit('players', playersPublic) }, 1000/60);

Which emits the players' public data JSON 60 times per second. I built a lot of architecture around this design, however I missed one potentially crucial thing: the key to each player's public data is also their socket.id, and by sending this JSON to all players I am practically sending the socket.ids of all players as well.

And so we get to my question: exactly how much of a bad practice is this? If a player has access to another player's socket.id, can they use this to for example emit data on their behalf or for any other malicious activity?

The socket.id is not used to verify any information that the players emit.

If this is bad practice, then what is a decent way to work around this problem? I did consider copying the data of players into an array and sending that instead, but this seems quite heavy in terms of memory, especially since it needs to happen 60 times per second.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: `can they use this to for example emit data on their behalf or for any other malicious activity?`   No, as long as your not sending the socket id as a way to update, the main thing you need to worry about is wherever your socket's are over http or https, as this is what would prevent man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Thank you so much for this reply. I did post a question about socket.io security earlier and I did get a warning about so-called man in the middle attacks but I did not get much elaboration on this subject.

How do I ensure that my sockets are over https? I'd be immeasurably grateful if you could give a more detailed explanation.

I am sorry for my incompetence. I don't have much experience in this department.

Comment: If your website is running over `https`, then your good to go, the `socket.io` will implicitly be `wss`, as this will be going via `https` upgrade.   IOW: If your website starts `https://` and you have that lock symbol in the url bar.  If not you will need to look into making your website use `https`, if you want to go the whole `node.js` route, have a look a redbird -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/redbird  it make using LetsEncrypt  to get an SSL cert really easy.